# How do I turn the play pause button off on vimeo embed?

Tags: embed, vimeo

I am embedding a video from vimeo into a live event and need to turn autoplay on and the play pause button off so users cannot control the video

Answer (score -2):

Please read the code that I will post.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5L3wKniOnro?autoplay=1&controls=0" width="600" height="400" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**We c'ant disable the play and pause button because when you put the url
in the code the app that you take the video from it like YouTube or Vimeo decide this.We can disable full screen  and hide the Play and pause button when we put controls=0.  This is a code of a embedded video. The video start automatically when you put after the link of the video?autoplay=1.**

Comment: That's for YouTube -- the question is about Vimeo.